# Tridion content manager homepage showing error after adding the Event System DLL

Tags: event-system

SDL Tridion 2011 SP1

Event DLL created with .NET version 4.0

After adding the below line in `Tridion.ContentManager.config` file:

- Add a reference to the DLL under the extensions element:

   `<add assemblyFileName="{PATH}\Filename.dll"/>`
- Restart COM+
- Restart `Tridion Content Manager Service Host` Windows Service

CMS got down and showing below error:

> An attempt was made to load an assembly from a network location which would have caused the assembly to be sandboxed in previous versions of the .NET Framework. This release of the .NET Framework does not enable CAS policy by default, so this load may be dangerous. If this load is not intended to sandbox the assembly, please enable the loadFromRemoteSources switch. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=155569 for more information.
>
> Unable to get LangID of User (tcm:0-99-65552). Initialization of the extension 'D:\Tridion\ProgramFiles\bin\EventExtension.dll' failed.

Please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open the Properties of the DLL on the server and click the **Unblock** button at the bottom of the dialog.

That should fix the issue.